# Adding an enterprise keyword value from search results using hover panel

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-search

SharePoint Enterprise Search is crawling SharePoint 2010 content and returning the expected results.

The requirement is to add "Enterprise keyword" value from the search results page for the selected document using the Hover panel. Each document already contains the metadata field (Enterprise Keyword).

By modifying the Search Display Template in SP2013 a hyperlink has been added in the Hover Panel as shown below.

When the "Add keyword" hyperlink is selected from the Hover panel it is required to populate the 'Enterprise Keyword' field with predefined value.

Help with an approach to achieve the above functionality (with references) greatly appreciated.
[image]